# Создать 2-мерный список 5х5. Задать номер строки и вывести все элементы, которые находятся в строке с этим номером. python

Tags: python

Не могу Создать 2-мерный список 5х5. Задать номер строки и вывести все элементы, которые находятся в строке с этим номером. python
Помогите

```
list = [];
i = 0;
while i < 5:
    new = [i , i, i, i, i]
    list.append(new);
    i += 1;

inputRow = int(input("Заданая строка: "));

for row in list:
    for elem in row:
        if elem == inputRow:
            print(elem);
print(list)
```

это примерный код но нужно что выводило элементы которые находятся в строке с этим номером

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1) Не называйте свою переменную `list`, это тип/функция питона, назовите лучше `lst` 2) В `lst[inputRow]` будет искомая строка матрицы, перебирать список чтобы её найти не нужно. Вот элементы этой строки нужно перебрать.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2):

Для вывода достаточно просто обратиться к строке списка по индексу, и перебрать ее. List - это тип объекта в языке Python, и данное название для списка недопустимо. Поэтому я использую list_

```
list_ = [];
i = 0;
while i < 5:
    new = [i , i, i, i, i]
    list_.append(new);
    i += 1;

inputRow = int(input("Заданая строка: "));

for i in list_[inputRow]:
    print(i)
```

Comment: чтоб через for не перебирать и вывести в одну строку, можно так написать `print(*list_[inputRow])`. И напишите в ответе для ТС, зачем вы нижнее подчеркивание используете в названии переменной.

Comment: @Dmitry Вопрос спрашивает явно новичок, и я показал наиболее простой и понятный способ. Про название поправлю.